# Android WebView Causes NullPointer

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

Having a really odd problem when trying to create a web view in an activity.

I was following the Android WebView guide to do this (http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html)

My app has a main menu with a button on it that leads to an activity that is supposed to open a web view.  It works just fine when I use an Intent, but I need more flexibility so that isn't really an option.

Here is my webview.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<WebView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/webview"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
</WebView>
```

This is what is in my WebView Activity file:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    WebView webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    diningWebView.loadUrl(http://www.google.com);
}
```

The problem is that my findViewById() is returning null, but I don't know why.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot your setContentView()

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView( R.layout.webview );   

    WebView webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    diningWebView.loadUrl(http://www.google.com);
}
```

Comment: Wow, totally forgot about that since I had been using a simple Intent before haha

Is there any way to get the ActionBar into the webview?

Comment: If this answer was sufficient, please mark it as the correct answer. And as far as I know the actionbar exists outside of even the activity. What would you want with the actionbar inside your layout? For navigation purposes? You could put the webview inside a linear layout and put some buttons above the webview?

Comment: Don't worry, I didn't forget to mark your answer, Stackoverflow just wanted me to wait 5 minutes :)

And yeah, my app has a lot of different menus, and I wanted to use the ActionBar across all of them to make the theme more unified.

Comment: You can still use your actionbar just like in any other activity. You can inflate a menu into it and use it to navigate your WebView. That's definitely do-able!

Answer (score 0):

For the record, one more possible reason: there are several different layouts, like for portrait and landscape, but not all of them define the WebView.